# In Tcl, why do I have to use quotes and curly braces for expr's argument when comparing two string literals?

Tags: arguments, tcl, equality, string-literals, expr

I wanna compare two literal strings using `expr` command in Tcl. The correct command is:

`expr {"string1" == "string1"}`

In my understanding, curly braces in Tcl is used to prevent substitution. But there is no variables in the comparison because I only compare string literals. For another, since words are separated by whitespace in Tcl command, if I don't use space, there is no need to group the math expression into a single word. So, I think I can remove both quotes and curly braces. But I got errors if do that. Specifically, if I remove quotes, the error is:

`% expr {string1==string1}`

`invalid bareword "string1"`

`in expression "string1==string1";`

`should be "$string1" or "{string1}" or "string1(...)" or ...`

If I remove curly braces, the error is:

`% expr "string1"=="string1"`

`extra characters after close-quote`

I don't understand why there are these errors. Can you explain for me? Thank you.

Comment: Remember `expr` has its own domain specific language that's different from normal tcl rules.

Comment: Might read https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Brace+your+expr%2Dessions

Answer (score 0):

You should (almost) always put braces round an `expr` expression; they make the semantics simple enough that Tcl can compile the expression ahead of time, giving a very nice speed boost. That locking down of the semantics also makes the code a lot safer.

The syntax of expressions (as described in the manual) requires strings to be in double quotes (substitutes using Tcl rules) or braces (unsubstituted), and always has done. Technically, there are exceptions for boolean literals and a few other things (such as `Inf` which is a floating point value but not syntactically so in the parser), but they're all explicit exceptions for definite known words.

Comment: The exception for not putting braces round an `expr` argument is when you are taking the expression from a variable or are otherwise generating it (a technique that ought to be rare these days). Most of the time you shouldn't do that, and you really are best to not mix literal and generated expressions if possible. Use the braces; chances it will fix far more problems that it could ever cause!